# Rails limit records by property

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, subquery

I have a two models `Category` and `Call`.

Call belongs_to Category

`Call` has `category_id` and `priority`.

I need to get only 10 calls from each category (the ones with lower priority first).

Is there any way to get this by a single query?

Comment: seems like standard SQL to me, just check sur ActiveRecord doc to do that but I think it should be possible

Comment: @SylvainChaugny I checked but didn't find anything usefull

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it like this:

```
Call.from("(select calls.*, row_number() over (partition by category_id order by priority) as num 
            from calls) c")
    .where("num <= 10")
    .select("c.id, c.category_id, c.priority")
```